# design object with open, print and close which call normal open, print and close

Tags: perl, oop

I design a class for configuring items, this class may either read the configuration, either write into it.

I would like to write an method called open, print and close (just as file handler), but since my class write to files, I need to call the 'normal' function open, print and close.

How can I do?

Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the native methods via `CORE::`, eg in your method `open()`:

```
sub open {
   # ...
   CORE::open(my $fh, '>', 'foo');
   CORE::print($fh, 'bar');
   CORE::close($fh);
}
```

See [perldoc CORE](http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html)

Comment: am I sure, that your method must have name `write`?

Comment: @amon: thx, yes it's `CORE` not `Core` .. @loldop: Sorry, I don't understand your question